# Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to search on multiple tables parallely using Hibernate Search (using FullTextSession) for search by keyword on the database??

Responses from the developers are appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In our project we have method to search per one table/entity:

**List< Object[] > multiFieldSearch(Class< ? > entityClass, List fields, Sort sort, String[] projectionFields, int maxResultsCount);**

You can create several thread to search in different tables/entities and then aggregate all result in the way you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response Yurii,but the thing is that I am doing global search on my database.That is only one term will be coming from the web page.Now how to check that this word belongs to which table and how to do it?

Comment: We use enum with entity and fields we need to search: smthing `CITY(City.class, new String[] { "id", "name", "country.id" })`
You can add a property "table" and in implementation of **multiFieldSearch** set to this property entityClass.

Comment: Please will you more elaborate it Yurii,look I have 18 tables in my database,for one table I am able to search using Apache Lucene,even I tried with FullTextSession of Hibernate Search,that too again with 1 table,I am able to search but,how to apply for multiple tables..thats the main issue..thanks for your reponses ..kindly elaborate your idea Yurii

-Garima

Comment: We have interface **HSearchService** with inner enum EntityFields that lucene will index in our app:
`CITY(City.class, new String[] { "id", "name", "country.id" }),`
`EDUCATION(Education.class, new String[] { "id", "type.id", "value" }),`

I'm suggesting you add your 18 entity here with all property you need and also add _table_ property. 
Also to not index every time you add/remove/update/delete some entity implement **EntityIndexingInterceptor** this interceptor.

We have several methods to search smth like this
**multiFieldSearch(Class<?> entityClass, List<MultiFieldSearch> fields)**.

Comment: You can create your own methods **List<Object[]> multiFieldSearchMust(List<Class<?>> entityClass, List<MultiFieldSearch> fields)** and in it implementation set to "table" property -> Class<?> you search by.

Comment: List<Job> jobs = session.createQuery("from Job").list();
   
   for (Job job : jobs) {
       fullTextSession.index(job);
   }
   
   MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser( new String[]{"name", "description"},
     new StandardAnalyzer());
   org.apache.lucene.search.Query query;
   
      query = parser.parse("Plumber");
   
   org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery( query, Job.class );
   List result = hibQuery.list();
     System.out.println("Result : "+result.size()+result);

Comment: As the result you get what you want? Or for you isn't enought to have information only about entity?

Comment: Yes for this only entity I am getting the result but it is like I am hard-coding it.See the thing is that here in session.createQuery() I am passing one single entity name i.e Job that is the indexes will be created and searching will only happen in this table itself..But my query is that for entire 18 tables I cant take it from session,I mean how to differentiate that whatever term user is passing,belongs to which entity,MultiFieldSearch will perform searching on the fields of one class??or at a time I can pass like List<Object[Job,User,Trade]>multiFieldSearchMust(List<Job,User,Trade...>>)?

Comment: Yurii I feel like you will be able to understand my point of searching,I am googling for it since 3 weeks(24*7 ;)) but m unable to get any clue for it,even I am new to coding domain itself,hibernate search,lucene evrything is new to me,Kindly Help..

Comment: I will research something in soon time, if it possible, because I think it is quite enought to know entity type.

Comment: Ok,same here will research on it

Comment: I can't find exact article about how we implement it.
_http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html_single/_ Here is oficial documentation about hibernate search and lucene index.
How we use it: we have one big index in separate machine throught all over entity, for example **Country** and **City**. Create query, something like that: ((select country.name={inputValue}))((select city.name={inputValue}*). Parse in on back-end and lucene index itself search throught several entities. I cant send you a code, because it is prohibited our security police.

Comment: Also there are great FAQ: **http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ**. Enjoy it :)

Comment: ya Yurii I studied over this document docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html_single , I also understand about the policies,for your guide I really appreciate.I am still trying with the code.Now again I am facing the problem continuing with 1 table itself

Comment: List<People> result = new ArrayList<People>();
       Session session =HibernateUtil.getSession();

Comment: FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

Comment: QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( People.class ).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = (org.apache.lucene.search.Query) qb
  .keyword()
  .onFields("name", "phone", "username")
  .matching(str).createQuery();

Comment: Now using the lucene query builder I am paasing the querystring and the entity class to the parser and just displaying the result ,still not working,can you rectify the code?